# Comparing IDs from entities hql

Tags: java, hibernate

So i'd like to to compare two IDs from my two entities which are connected, well i think better explanation will be if i show u a code

OfferOrder.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "offer_order", schema = "srp")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence_generator", sequenceName = "srp.offer_order_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false, exclude = { "offerOrderProjectRel", "associatedOrder" })
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class OfferOrder extends BaseEntity {
[...]

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pk.offerOrder")
    private Set<OfferOrderProjectRel> offerOrderProjectRel = new HashSet<OfferOrderProjectRel>();
[..]
}
```

The ID is in BaseEntity

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequence_generator")
protected Long id;
```

And i have to compare this ID with my ID from OfferOrderProjectRel

```
    @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "offer_order_project_rel", schema = "srp")
    @AssociationOverrides({
            @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.offerOrder",
                    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "offer_order_id")),
            @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.project",
                    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")) })
    @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
    @ToString(callSuper = true)
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class OfferOrderProjectRel {

        @EmbeddedId
        private OfferOrderProjectRelId pk = new OfferOrderProjectRelId();

        @Transient
        @NotNull
        private OfferOrder offerOrder;

}
```

Which has embeddedID from OfferORderProjectRelId

```
@Embeddable
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class OfferOrderProjectRelId implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    private OfferOrder offerOrder;

}
```

So after i show u important stuff (:P) im creating question to hibernate

```
private static final String SELECT_OOPR_TO_SEND = "SELECT R " +
                                                  "FROM OfferOrderProjectRel R, OfferOrder O, Project P " +
                                                  "WHERE R.project.id = P.id and O.id = R.offerOrder.id " +
                                                  "and O.type = 'ORDER' and (P.status = 'PENDING' or P.status ='PROTECTED')" ;
```

As you can see im connecting another entity there but once i get pass through this i will able to do another one i think.

So when i lauch this hql i get that errror

> org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: **offerOrder**(or **project**) of:
>   pl.srp.beans.schema.srp.OfferOrderProjectRel [SELECT R FROM
>   pl.srp.beans.schema.srp.OfferOrderProjectRel R,
>   pl.srp.beans.schema.srp.OfferOrder O, pl.srp.beans.schema.srp.Project
>   P WHERE R.project.id = P.id  and O.id = R.offerOrder.id and O.type =
>   'ORDER' and (P.status = 'PENDING' or P.status ='PROTECTED')]

I tried also `O = R.offerOrder` etc. So wheres my issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You need public setters and getters for `offerOrder`, without a getter the private variable can't be called

Comment: ah i forget to mention that getters and setters are automaticly made for offerOrder etc

Comment: anyway i get it but using R.pk.offerOrder. Thanks for an answer ;)